# Dangerous Planet

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, space-exploration, space-colonization

A while back I read a soft cover book, I have looked around and found similar titles but not it exactly. The first part is about a colony on a dangerous planet covered in forest. The second part in this story is where the main protagonist goes to a new planet with the colony, and this new planet is a desert.

On the first planet the protagonist arrives in a craft, and after a few events dealing with the hostile jungle that surrounds the clearing the colony made, he becomes a sort of leader helping the people to survive. I feel like I remember him meeting his lover on the first planet and she stays his lover through the second planet as well.

Comment: Any more details you can remember?  Right now I'm thinking it's possibly Harry Harrison's Deathworld and Deathworld II which matches all those elements I believe but it's a little vague so I'm not sure.  Do you remember anything like telepathy being involved in the first book, or in the second if society has broken up into different clans which are each jealousy guarding one particular type of technological secret, but that tendency leaving them all more primitive than if they united?

Comment: 'A while back' - any more detail? Late '90s? Early '30s? Also, what language was it in? English?

Comment: Planet of adventures was it, thank you so much to @megha for that answer. Though i will have to read deathworld series as well. It has been so long since i read the stories that everything had become vague memories.

Comment: @AlexRedden Don't forget to mark the correct answer as solved down below!

Answer (score 2):

This might be ["Planets of Adventure"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/406918.Planets_of_Adventure) by Murray Leinster - I found it [as an ebook](http://www.baen.com/planets-of-adventure.html), but it is also available as a softcover.  The second ~half of the book, is called "the Planet Explorer" and has a set of short stories, starting with "Solar Constant", which centers around a character named Bordman, who is an engineer and Colonial Survey Officer, who travels to different planets and tries to make sure everything is going well, and who ends up fixing problems as he finds them.

> The first part is about a colony on a dangerous planet covered in forest. The second part in this story is where the main protagonist goes to a new planet with the colony, and this new planet is a desert.

The first story has him dealing with a planet which is becoming colder and freezing too much because of sunspots, and the second story is about a desert planet which had trouble from sandstorms.  Other planets include different locations, including an upside-down swamp, and a forested world (actually third in the series).

> On the first planet the protagonist arrives in a craft, and after a few events dealing with the hostile jungle that surrounds the clearing the colony made, he becomes a sort of leader helping the people to survive.

In the first story, he saves the colony and does become sort of a leader there - offering things to try and fix the problem and improving solutions until something works.  It is not exactly a forest world, but there is a forest world in the third story, and several other stories in the collection have forest or jungle settings (including the first half of the book which has a very dangerous jungle planet) which you might be mixing with this story.

> I feel like I remember him meeting his lover on the first planet and she stays his lover through the second planet as well.

He gets married, at the end of the first story - and there's a mention of subsequent adventures which call him away from his family, but who he gets back to between calls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it reminds me too of the Deathworld series by Harry Harrison featuring Jason dinAlt a professional gambler and adventurer.
Except the second planet you described may also be Felicity, home of nomad warrior tribes, which is in the third book in the series.

Comment: This seems to be intended to respond to starpilotsix's comment.